# Access iOS In-App Purchases from App Extension

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, ios-app-extension, auv3

Is it possible to perform and access iOS In-App Purchases from inside an App Extension? I want to have shared purchases between App Extension and the containing app.

I have an iOS App that contains an *AudioUnit v3* App Extension. The AUv3 runs in host apps such as AudioBus. It runs the same code as the containing app to access In-App Purchases. IAPs done from the containing app are working, but when done from the AUv3 I get the error `SKErrorClientInvalid` (`SKErrorDomain`) *Could not connect to iTunes Store*.

The containing app's bundle identifier is like `com.mycompany.MyAppName`, and the AUv3's bundle identifier is like `com.mycompany.MyAppName.MyAppNameAUv3`. On App Store Connect, the In-App Purchases are registered for the containing app.

Do I need to do set up something else in order for this to work?